# Notes on iOS 7 crashing on Startup

Tags: ios, bug, notes.app

After upgrading to iOS 7 the standard Notes app crashes when starting it.

I'm running iOS 7.0 and have reproduced this after a clean power down of the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out so I'll share it if it helps someone else:

- Instead of tapping on the Notes icon, search for a specific note in spotlight then open that note.

After that Notes will work normally again.

(Apple knows about the bug but they didn't fix it in time for the release.)

Answer (score 2):

You could also open Siri and tell Siri

Note hello

I would note "hello" for you click on it and it opens notes and it would work like normall

Comment: Also a clever way to bypass the default view when starting notes.